# Skimage: how to combine two grayscale images into a channel two image

Tags: python, scikit-image

I have two grayscale images. There I would like to make a channel 2 image using that two grayscale images. There I tried using `np.dstack` and `np.concatenate`, There all return a image size of `540x1440`. I could not get `540 x 720 x 2` image format. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance

```
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import numpy as np

image1 = imread("main_directory/test1.png")
grayImage1 = rgb2gray(image1) # 540 x 720

image2 = imread("main_directory/test2.png")
grayImage2 = rgb2gray(image2) # 540 x 720

# channel two image
# concatenateGray = np.dstack((grayImage1 , grayImage2)) # 540 x 1440 which seems incorrect
# concatenateGray = np.concatenate((grayImage1, grayImage2), axis=2) # 540x 1440 which seems also incorrect
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to reshape them to add a third axis, then concatenate along that axis.  The reshape operation takes no time, since the data doesn't change.

```
concatenateGray = np.concatenate((grayImage1.reshape((20,20,1)), grayImage2.reshape((20,20,1)), axis=2)
```

BTW, there is no standard image format with two components per pixel, so I'm not sure what you're going to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the third `axis` or `channel` to your images:

```py
grayImage1_new = grayImage1.reshape(540,720,1)
grayImage2_new = grayImage2.reshape(540,720,1)
```

2. Use [`Alpha blending`](https://learnopencv.com/alpha-blending-using-opencv-cpp-python/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20alpha%20blending%3F%20Alpha%20blending%20is%20the,called%20the%20alpha%20mask%20or%20the%20alpha%20matte.) in python

```py
alpha = 0.4
combined_image = np.zeros(grayImage1_new.shape,dtype=grayImage1_new.dtype)
combined_image[:,:,:] = (alpha * grayImage1_new[:,:,:]) + ((1-alpha) * grayImage2_new[:,:,:])
```

---

The final Code:

```py
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import numpy as np

image1 = imread("main_directory/test1.png")
grayImage1 = rgb2gray(image1) # 540 x 720

image2 = imread("main_directory/test2.png")
grayImage2 = rgb2gray(image2) # 540 x 720

grayImage1_new = grayImage1.reshape(540,720,1)
grayImage2_new = grayImage2.reshape(540,720,1) 

alpha = 0.4
combined_image= np.zeros(grayImage1_new.shape,dtype=grayImage1_new.dtype)
combined_image[:,:,:] = (alpha * grayImage1_new[:,:,:]) + ((1-alpha) * grayImage2_new[:,:,:])
```